# gaussian and laplacian MatLab Project

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, gaussian

I am unsure how to start this problem, any help will be much appreciated.

"Generate a Gaussian random variable, and a Laplacian random variable. Choose a = 0 (zero mean)

Transmit the sequence using the following cases:

Gaussian noise (variance 0.1 and 1) and use two comparators: the first one will compare one single sample to 0, and the second one where you will compare the average of 100 samples (assumed to have been taken within the bit interval) and compare to 0 again.

If greater than 0, the bit should have been 1 and 0 otherwise. The comparison will be repeated for the case of unequal probability and the same threshold 0 (which may not be optimum).

Laplacian noise (variance 0.1 and 1) is to be the underlying contamination. Repeat the process.

Note that the detector will not be optimum in this case regardless of equal or unequal probabilities. The sequences are

Equal probabilities: 10001011000111101001­­ Unequal probabilities: 11001111011011101101"

Any advice as to where to start?

What I have done is this:

```
    %% Delevoped by Group 03
%James Hayek, Ashas Pathan, Paul Kieliszek
%Matlab Group Project
%Professor Mohammed Feknous 
%NJIT ECE 321 Random Signals and Noise

%% Clearing and closing all other open programs withing MatLab
close all
clc

%% Generation of a signal bpsk modulation
%This takes a set of random numbers and converts them to bits 0's & 1's
%The 2*X-1 will create -1's in place of the 0's from the bit conversion.
signal_i = 2*(rand(1,10^5)>0.5)-1;
signal_q = zeros(1,10^5);
%In communication systems we have two components
%which is why we have singal i and q
scatterplot(signal_i + 1i*signal_q);

%% Combining for complex representation
signal = complex(signal_i, signal_q);

p_signal = mean(abs(signal).^2) %Power of the signal

e_signal = (abs(signal).^2); %Energy of the signal

%% Adding some noise of a known variance
for var = 1/50:1/10:0.5
    noise = 1/sqrt(2)*(randn(1,10^5)+j*randn(1,10^5))*sqrt(var);

    addNoise = signal + noise;

%Plotting the above conditions to a graph
    figure(1);
    plot(real(addNoise),imag(addNoise),'*');
    drawnow('expose');
end

for snr = 0:1:10 %dB
    snr_lin = 10^(snr/10);
    ebno_lin = 10^((snr-3)/10);
    var = p_signal/snr_lin; %This is how we are finding noise variance
    var_ebno = p_signal/ebno_lin;

    noise = 1/sqrt(2)*(randn(1,10^5)+j*randn(1,10^5))*sqrt(var_ebno);

    addNoise = signal + noise; %We have now averaged/esimated
    %the noise to remove it from the signal plotting it to a second graph.

%Plotting the above conditions to a graph
    figure(2);
    plot(real(addNoise),imag(addNoise),'*');
    drawnow('expose');
end

%By pressing run, you will see an animation of the generated Gaussian
%Randon signal with noise for graph 1, and the estimated noise removed for
%graph 2.
```

Is this a correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: This is not the place to get homework help. I suggest that you ask your teacher/TAs for help, re-read your textbook/notes, and spend some time programming and reading Matlab documentation/tutorials. If you have a specific programming-related question come back and show your code and clearly indicate what error or incorrect output you're getting.

Comment: No, this is just a place to get help for jobs that ppl don't know how to do? If the TA or professor was more helpful in the question and answers I woudn't of posted here. I have asked questions becasue I intended on learning and didn't know where to start. If you dont't want to help, don't, but there is no need for no constructive help. Btw, if you saw my prior threads I HAVE posted code. NOONE commented on it. So I restated the question to include the entire scope of hte problem.

Comment: Now that I have included my code to show I have read the text book, and did research on MatLab, do you think I can get a more constructive comment?